# Showing Dialog with Auto_Route and BlocListener

Tags: flutter, dialog, bloc

I'm developing an app that diplays an alert every time the user turns off the device's Wifi and Mobile Data. I'm also using Auto_Route for navigation.

Here's the code so far:

```
class AppWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  AppWidget({super.key});
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState> messengerKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RepositoryProvider(
      create: (_) => getIt<CPlusNetworkRepository>(),
      child: BlocProvider(
          create: (_) => getIt<ConnectionStatusBloc>()
          ..add(const StreamSubsricptionRequested()),
          child: BlocListener<ConnectionStatusBloc, ConnectionStatusState>(
             listener: (context, state) {
                state.map(
                  connected: (_) {},
                  disconnected: (_) async {
                    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async{
                       await showCupertinoDialog(
                         context: context,
                         builder: (context) => const CupertinoAlertDialog(
                           title: Text('Alert'),
                           content: Text('Please switch on Wifi/Mobile Data'),
                         ),
                       );
                    });
                  },
                  unknown: (_) {},
                );
             },
          child: MaterialApp.router(  
             scaffoldMessengerKey: messengerKey,
             routeInformationParser: appRouter.defaultRouteParser(),
             routerDelegate: appRouter.delegate(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> E/flutter ( 9910): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.

> E/flutter ( 9910): The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.

I know there's somethig inherently wrong with what I'm trying to do but I can't seem to find the correct way to approach this.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to show a Dialog, which requires a `Navigator` to be placed anywhere before it in the widget tree.
A solution would be to place the listener below your `Material`, so it has `Navigator` to find up in his `BuildContext`

Comment: Thanks! I managed it with the 'builder' parameter of the MaterialApp.router. Cheers!